# getCellLocation returns null

Tags: android, cellid

I am trying to access the current cell location information. When I
try to call `getCellLocation()`, it returns `null`.

I am unable to reason out this.. the same code works on 1.5 but fails
on 1.6 or 2.1. (Tested on G1 with 1.6 and HTC legend 2.1.)

Can someone help me in correcting this bug? My code is below.

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)
getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

outputView.append("Device type:" + tMgr.getPhoneType() + "\n");

GsmCellLocation gsmCellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) tMgr.getCellLocation();
if (gsmCellLocation != null) {
    String mCellId = "" + gsmCellLocation.getCid();
    String mLAC = "" + gsmCellLocation.getLac();
    Log.d("SDKService", "Cell Id: " + mCellId + " LAC: " + mLAC);
    outputView.append("Cell Id: " + mCellId + " LAC: " + mLAC + "\n");
}
```

Also, I have added the following permissions :

- `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
- `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`
- `CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES`

Do I need to add any other permissions?

Kindly let me know where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

getCellLocation() returns null, if current location is not available.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCellLocation%28%29

Additionally check for the presence of Basebandtype information in your phone settings.